# Access-Control-Allow-Origin option not working - CORS Issue

Tags: reactjs, cors, fetch-api

I have a react app, in which I am trying to make an API call using fetch() method.

`fetch("https://example.com/user");` something like this. but it is throwing an error like below.

> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:3000' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

my project is running on `localhost:3000` and calling API like `https://example.com/user`.

I kept `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

```js
fetch("https://example.com/user", {
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  })
```

but got below error.

> Access to fetch at 'https://example.com/user` from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

tried `mode:no-cors`

```js
fetch("https://example.com/user", {
  headers: {
     "mode":"no-cors"
  })
```

but got same error i.e.

> Access to fetch at 'https://example.com/user` from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

for both options

```js
fetch("https://example.com/user", {
  headers: {
     "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
     "mode":"no-cors"
  })
```

got the below error.

> Access to fetch at 'https://example.com/user`' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: You have to set the CORS from API

Comment: you can add `"proxy": "https://example.com"` inside package.json and then call `/user` in fetch or use [http-proxy-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware)

Comment: You cannot control CORS policy with fetch configuration in browser. You can either modify your API to add your localhost to allowed hosts list, either to use CRA Proxy feature: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Comment: @usama, when tried  `"proxy": "https://example.com"` is not starting `npm start` and giving error  `Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options.allowedHosts[0] should be a non-empty string.`

Comment: [This link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#invalid-host-header-errors-after-configuring-proxy) may help you which is the section from the link posted in above comment. OR check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70413065/13405106)

Answer (score -1):

Enable CORS in the API Gateway console and added 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" and click "Enable CORS and replace existing CORS Header" button.

OR

change setting of CORS, you need to change setting of API Gateway to Access-Control-Allow-Origin= '*'

Comment: Setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin to '*" will open up everything. be very specific as to what domains can access your service

Comment: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000/" giving same error.

Comment: @Shripada CORS is not access control

Answer (score -2):

It's a security problem to get api request outside of other domains.
CORS is related for API, not frontend.
In order to accept your request from localhost:3000, CORS header should be set in API part.

Comment: If that is the case, then what is the use of these options "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
     "mode":"no-cors". These are also mentioned in mdn docs.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: it's for server part configuration.

Comment: @ram - You're misunderstanding what `no-cors` means. it doesn't mean "bypass the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) for me." That would make the SOP completely pointless. It means (loosely) "I know this is a cross-origin request and I won't see the response; that's okay. Also, don't bother with preflight." [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569895/fetch-api-why-use-the-no-cors-mode-if-the-response-is-opaque).